# How does optimization happen in the parameters of the algorithms in sci-kit learn library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

When Machine Learning is seen mathematically, we have cost functions, to reduce the error in the prediction for the next time and we keep on optimizing the parameters of the equation/s used in the particular algorithm.

I wonder where does this optimization happen in the library
[Sci-kit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/).
There is no function for doing this job, so far I know,there are rather a bunch of [algorithms as functions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning).

Can someone please tell me how do I optimize those parameters in sci-kit learn, and is there a way to do it in the mentioned library or is it just for learning purposes.
I saw the code of library of [logistic regression](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py#L1191) but got nothing.

Any effort is appreciated.

Comment: "I saw the code of library of logistic regression but got nothing" - this is exactly where you should be looking for answers to your question - on GitHub. As far as I know, the library will do the optimisation automatically, so you don't have to "optimize those parameters in sci-kit learn"

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [GridsearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)? That's the go-to for optimizing parameters across sklearn models

Comment: Ok, I got a new problem here
GridsearchCV does allow me to use different values of haperparameters but it carriesout cross validation as well, which creates  new problem, as I got out of this discussion. Is there another way out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102900/not-getting-better-results-after-using-gridsearchcv-rather-getting-better-man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
[GridsearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) is the answer, thats what I was looking for.
I think it allows us to choose the values of alpha, c and number of iterations, therefore, not allowing to alter the values of weights directly and I think thats ok or thats how we'd assign values to those parameters after carrying out the same process independtly.
This [article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-tune-algorithm-parameters-with-scikit-learn/) helped me to understand it well.

Comment: Hey, I think you are getting parameters and hyperparameters mixed up. Ok for a beginner, but important to learn the difference.

Comment: what do you mean by parameters and hyperparameters being mixed up.Apologies if thats a newbie question..actually i am a newbie

Comment: Parameters are the weights inside a model and a determined by the optimization algorithm used, such as gradient descent. Hyperparameters are settings that you need before the model runs, such as alpha, learning rate, max epochs etc. GridSearch is a way to do hyperparameter tuning. So the algorithms to optimize parameters and hyperparamters are two very different things. It will be much easier for you to get help after you learn the vocabulary a little better, so maybe go study up on the various vocabulary terms. It's ok, everyone has to start somewhere. Good luck.

Comment: wow,I am getting it, please tell me if I am right.When we change values of  hyperparameters like alpha, aren't we doing that to get the optimal values for parameters.Like in gradient descent I use a number of values of alpha only to find best value for theta, i.e. a parameter

Comment: Pretty much yes. There's no single "best" theta. But we try to find the best hyperparamters that give the model the best chances of finding the best approximation to how we would we define what best parameters mean. But other than this inherit fuzziness, now you seem to get it.