# Not getting better results after using gridsearchCV(), rather getting better manually

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I was trying  to learn working of gridsearchCV, by testing it on Knearistneighbors.
When I assigned n_neighbors = 9 my classifier gave a score of 0.9122807017543859

but when I used gridsearchCV while giving it n_neighbors = 9, in the list,I get the score of 0.8947368421052632.

What could possibly be the reason?
Any effort is appreciated.
Here's my code

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as splitter
import pickle       
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier  
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Data pre-processing  <-----------------------

data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
p=data
add=data.target.reshape(569,1)  
columns = np.append(data.feature_names, 
                    data.target_names[0],
                    axis=None)
data = np.append(data.data,
                 add,
                 axis=1)                        
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = splitter(p.data,
                                         p.target,
                                         test_size=0.3,
                                         random_state=12)




gauss = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=9)

param_grid={'n_neighbors':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,10]}

gausCV = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(),param_grid,verbose=False)


gauss.fit(X_train,y_train)
gausCV.fit(X_train,y_train)

print(gauss.score(X_test,y_test))
print(gausCV.score(X_test,y_test))
```

this is what I got

```
0.9122807017543859
0.8947368421052632
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in the number of neighbors, but in the "cross validation". The `GridSearchCV` process not only attempts all of the values that you have in the `param_grid`, but also performs some data manipulation: the "folds" of the data. This is resampling data mulitple times so as to help make the final classifier as robust to new data as possible. Given how close the scores are that you get between the `gauss` and `gausCV` models, it is almost certain that the data being drawn is affecting the results, but not heavily.

This is a good example of why just accepting a model with the highest "score" might not always be the best path: I would have greater faith in a model that scored well having gone through cross-validation than one that had not (all else equal).

[Here is a good description](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) of what is going on when you run cross-validation.

Comment: Wow, so GridSearchCV is performing cross validation and using my set of values I gave it, right?
So, is there a way that I'd want only hyperparameters to change and find the optimum model, i.e. I don't want cross validation to happen right now.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: If you really want to hold the data constant for each run of the hyperparameters, I think your best bet is to loop through each individual parameter to run the model, and store out the score to either review or compare in a function you create. Since there are multiple parameters, it might mean multiple loops, which will get slow.

Comment: Definitely,that's with n_neighbors,  but when it's C or alpha,  what do I do there. Do we have any other function for that. I tried but found none